# Itextsharp - check to see if adding an element will create a new page

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm using ITextSharp to convert an HTML document into PDF. I use HTMLWorker.ParseToList and loop through each item in turn. That works fine, however the first page is required to have different margin sizes to the subsequent pages. I can do this by calling MyDocument.NewPage() and calling MyDocument.SetMargins().
My problem occurs when trying to detect the page transitions.
I can use a loop to keep track of page transitions, then call NewPage() and reset the margins, however, this can only happen once I've actually added a paragraph that wraps onto a new page, leaving an entire page that's practically white-space.
I need a way of pre-emptively detecting if the page will change if I add a certain Paragraph object.
I've tried using ColumnText.Go(true) to simulate it (and if the result of that is ColumnText.NO_MORE_COLUMN, then make it a page break), unfortunately that appears to be flakey at best, and tends to detect page breaks in entirely the wrong places.
Here's my current code:

```
            ColumnText simulation = new ColumnText(Writer.DirectContent);
            simulation.SetSimpleColumn(Writer.PageSize);   
            bool FirstPage = true;
            foreach (var item in ItemList)
            {
                var para = new Paragraph("", Normal);
                para.AddAll(item.Chunks);                    
                para.SpacingAfter = 10;
                foreach (Chunk c in item.Chunks)
                {
                    simulation.AddText(c);
                }
                if(FirstPage) {
                    int simresult = simulation.Go(true);
                    if(simresult == (int)ColumnText.NO_MORE_COLUMN)
                    {
                        textDocument.SetMargins(100,100,100,100);
                        textDocument.NewPage();    
                        FirstPage = false;                 
                    }
                }

                textDocument.Add(para);
            }
```

This results in it not detecting a page break until the end of page 2. Which is no good.

The only way I've found to get it working is to HALF the height going into simulation.SetSimpleColumn.

It works, but I don't know why, and honestly, that's no good. If anyone can give me any insight that'd be great.

---

Thanks to Alexis I've worked it out. The ITextSharp follows the Java event model pretty thoroughly, which is annoying since I was looking for events in the Writer and Document directly.
First I had to create a class that overrode PdfPageEventHelper:

```
internal class MainTextEventsHandler : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        document.SetMargins(document.LeftMargin, document.LeftMargin, document.TopMargin, document.BottomMargin); //Mirror the horizontal margins
        document.NewPage(); //do this otherwise the margins won't take
    }
}
```

Next, I set the PageEvent property of the Writer object, and I modified my loop to remove the simulation.

```
        Writer.PageEvent = new MainTextEventsHandler();
        foreach (var item in ItemList)
        {
            var para = new Paragraph("", Normal);
            para.AddAll(item.Chunks);
            /* per-paragraph stuff here */
            para.SpacingAfter = 10;                    
            textDocument.Add(para);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Page Events](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=204), in particular [onStartPage](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=219) and/or [onEndPage](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=220) to determine if you have to change the margins of the document.

Please note that these examples are for the Java version, but the conversion to iTextSharp should be straightforward.

Comment: It does look like they've just directly ported the Java to C# and ignored the C# events model. I had to create a seperate mini-class with a single function in it (override OnStartPage), that inherited PdfPageEventHelper and put my .SetMargins and .NewPage() calls in there. Works fine now, don't even need the simulation, but what was wrong with just giving the object itself events?

Comment: @Canazza I'm no iText-committer so I really can't tell. Maybe you could ask that on the [iText mailing-list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions). Please note that you'll have to subscribe to the list to be able to post there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
public const string pageBreakHtmlMarker = "<!-- pageBreak -->";
public MemoryStream htmlToPdf(string html)
{
    MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
    string[] sep = new string[] { pageBreakHtmlMarker };
    string[] arrHtml = html.Split(sep, 9999, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    htmlToPdf(arrHtml, ref msOutput);
    return msOutput;
}
private void htmlToPdf(string[] arrHtmlPages, ref MemoryStream msOutput)
{
    using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30))
    {
        using (HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document))
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput); // writer to listen doc ad direct a XML-stream to a file            
            document.Open();
            worker.StartDocument();
            foreach (string html in arrHtmlPages)
            {
                TextReader reader = new StringReader(html); // parse the html into the document
                worker.Parse(reader);
                document.Add(Chunk.NEXTPAGE);
            }
            worker.EndDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer? I don't understand how this will solve the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Sample snippet in Visual Basic

In `LoadPage` just use:

```
Dim pdfPageEvents As pdfPageEvents = New pdfPageEvents
writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memMemoryStream)
writer.CloseStream = False
writer.PageEvent = pdfPageEvents
doc.Open()
```

put this class to te same file or namespace

```
Public Class pdfPageEvents
    Inherits iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
    Private _strTitle As String, _strPrintFeatures As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal Title As String, ByVal PrintFeatures As String)
        _strTitle = Title
        _strPrintFeatures = PrintFeatures
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As PdfWriter, ByVal doc As Document)
        If InStr(_strPrintFeatures, "header") > 0 Then
            Dim fntFont As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", BaseFont.CP1250, True, 10, Font.NORMAL, New BaseColor(128, 128, 128))
            Dim imgImage As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../LocalResources/Images/print_company_logo_medium.png"))
            Dim tblTable As New PdfPTable(2)
            Dim celRightCell As PdfPCell

            tblTable.WidthPercentage = 100
            tblTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
            imgImage.ScalePercent(70)

            Dim celLeftCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(_strTitle, fntFont))
            celLeftCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
            celLeftCell.Border = 0
            celLeftCell.BorderWidthBottom = 0.5
            celLeftCell.BorderColorBottom = New BaseColor(128, 128, 128)
            celLeftCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM
            celLeftCell.PaddingBottom = 3
            tblTable.AddCell(celLeftCell)

            If InStr(_strPrintFeatures, "logo") > 0 Then
                celRightCell = New PdfPCell(imgImage)
            Else
                celRightCell = New PdfPCell(New Paragraph(""))
            End If

            celRightCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
            celRightCell.Border = 0
            celRightCell.BorderWidthBottom = 0.5
            celRightCell.BorderColorBottom = New BaseColor(128, 128, 128)
            celRightCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM
            celRightCell.PaddingBottom = 3
            tblTable.AddCell(celRightCell)

            doc.Add(tblTable)
            doc.Add(New Paragraph(vbNewLine))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnEndPage(ByVal writer As PdfWriter, ByVal doc As Document)
        If InStr(_strPrintFeatures, "footer") > 0 Then
            Dim fntFont As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", BaseFont.CP1250, True, 10, Font.NORMAL, New BaseColor(128, 128, 128))
            Dim tblTable As New PdfPTable(2)
            Dim strDate As String = IIf(InStr(_strPrintFeatures, "date") > 0, FormatDateTime(Date.Today, DateFormat.GeneralDate), "")

            tblTable.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width - doc.LeftMargin - doc.RightMargin
            tblTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER

            Dim celLeftCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(strDate, fntFont))
            celLeftCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
            celLeftCell.Border = 0
            celLeftCell.BorderWidthTop = 0.5
            celLeftCell.BorderColorTop = New BaseColor(128, 128, 128)
            celLeftCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM
            tblTable.AddCell(celLeftCell)

            Dim celRightCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(CStr(doc.PageNumber), fntFont))
            celRightCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT
            celRightCell.Border = 0
            celRightCell.BorderWidthTop = 0.5
            celRightCell.BorderColorTop = New BaseColor(128, 128, 128)
            celRightCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM
            tblTable.AddCell(celRightCell)
            tblTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, doc.LeftMargin, (doc.BottomMargin), writer.DirectContent)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer? I don't understand how this will solve the OP's question.